# Write a program which accepts two integers as a minimum and maximum limit and calculates total of how many 1s were their within the limit

Tags: java

For ex:

1) if user input 1 11 then it should print 4.

2) if user input 11 111 then it should print 34.

Comment: please do some research before you ask such basics. Also use the search function. There are a looot of answeres to it already

Comment: why 1 11 should print 4 and the same for 34 ?

Comment: here min number is 11 max number is 111 how many one is there?

Comment: 111 - 11 = 100, or 11 and 111 = 5 explain your logic

Comment: 1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 this range has 4   '1'  these are 1,10,11 like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advice looking into the math of your problem and come up with a clever algorithm that you then implement. The 1s are far from randomly distributed in a range of numbers that are count up ;-)

However there is always the brute force approach. 
(This is just to show a possibility and one of the worst ways to solve the problem)

```
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=11; i++)
    {
        String number = String.valueOf(i);
        while(number.contains("1"))
        {
            number= number.substring(number.indexOf("1")+1);
            count ++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

**EDIT:**
For those with an interest in better brute force version using log, mod and div (best I could come up with yet ^^):

```
    int count2 = 0;     
    for(int i = lowerbound; i<=upperbound; i++)
    {
        int temp = Math.abs(i); //make positive. No negative log 
        if(temp==0) //beware the log(0) trap 
            continue;
        int length = (int)(Math.log10(temp)+1); //count digits
        for(int j = length -1; j>=0 ; j--)  //inspect digit for digit
        {
            if(temp % 10 == 1)
            {
                count2 ++;
            }
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
    }
```

Tests done with a range from -1000000 to 1000000 measured with nano() (so no units). For CharAt approach see Tom Wellbrock s answer.
Even though log, % and / are quite slow mathematical operations the cost for a String creation is more expensive.

Without java Optimisation: :

- SubString: 14000002   time taken:

  - 18351768293
- Log: 14000002         time taken:

  - 2895089202
- CharAt: 14000002      time taken:

  - 13929667983

With java optimisation (creating Strings becomes a lot cheaper then, especially when they appear twice and all the little tweaks why we love java so much)

- SubString:14000002        time taken:

  - 1088103359
- Log:14000002          time taken:

  - 568686169
- CharAt:14000002       time taken:

  - 741721424

Comment: one more question can u expand this for minus numbers too?

Comment: What keeps you from using negative numbers? Just try it out.
Like:
    for(int i = -111; i<=-11; i++)

Answer (score 2):

Do it with `Java.util.Scanner`. Thats a really basic thing in java. I recommend you to do some research :) Here is an easy tutorial on that:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html

here an answere anyway:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    String anInputString;

    anInputString = user_input.next( );


    if (anInputString.equals("1 11")){
    System.out.println("4")
    }
    if (anInputString.equals("11 111"){
    System.out.println("34")
    }
}
```

edit:

if you want to achieve an output of "4" while your input lies between "1" and "11". Or "34" if its between "10" and "112" you should try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int anInputInt;

        anInputInt = user_input.nextInt( );

        if (0 < anInputInt && anInputInt < 11 ){ //if input is (1-10)
        System.out.println("4")
        }
        if (11 <= anInputInt && anInputInt <= 111){ //if input is (11-111)
        System.out.println("34")
        }
    }
```

Anyway you should edit your question :D I think many people are happy to help you, but just cant understand your question at all 0.0

**finally after I understood what you really want to do:**

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int anInputInt;

        anInputInt = user_input.nextInt( );

        if(anInputString < 0){
        anInputString = anInputstring*(-1);
        }

        int oneCount = 0;

        //gets all numbers in your specified range
        //if you want to start at number "xx" change the value of aNumberInRange likewise
        for (int aNumberInRange = 0; aNumberInRange < anInputInt; aNumberInRange++){ 

            String str = String.valueOf(aNumberInRange);

            //iterates through every character of an aNumberInRange and counts if a "1" occurs
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
               char c = str.charAt(i);        
               if (c == 1){
                oneCount++
               }
            }
        }
        system.out.println(oneCount);
      }
```

**For whoever reads this solution. The client wanted to count all the occurences of the number "1" in a specified range. This should also work with negative Numbers**

Comment: if you give a downvote please explain why! I gave an answere to the question. I would say a basic answere to an easy question. I dont see my flaw

Comment: this question is not easy as u think I think

Comment: please edit your question and explain it some more. Im sure that i can help you

Comment: count only one no matter any range for example 1 to 99999999999999 how many one in it

Comment: if I get you right you want to display how many "1"'s are in an input."3241241" for example would contain two "1"'s. Is that right?

Comment: Ohh now i get it XD you want to display in a specified range how many numbers contain 1's, more specified how many 1's there are in total. I will solve your problem in an hour I got a meeting

Comment: for example i will input 11   output should be 4  because     
1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 this range has 4 '1's these are 1,10,11 like this

Comment: Ok now its finally done! glad to help ya. please mark as answered :D

Comment: PLEASE say at least what didnt work. Didnt it compile? Is the output wrong?

Comment: output is wrong because when write input 11 output is just 2

Comment: just check it u will see then.

Comment: sorry i have no Ide at the moment. Now it should work. it seems that on for-loop didnt iterate as i thought. I fixed it already and hope it goes well now :P

Comment: Also as you desired the function will now work with negative numbers as well